# What does Mr World represent in the American Gods book?

Tags: character-analysis, symbolism, neil-gaiman, american-gods

The [American Gods Wikia site](https://americangods.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._World) claims that Mr World is a personification of globalisation. That definitely seems to be true in the TV series (see [the creepiest rant ever made about salsa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tfjJcLmyfY)), but in the novel he seems a much more mysterious figure, IIRC never even *seen* "on stage" until near the very end, when

> it's revealed that he's actually Loki (aka Low-Key), and only "leading" the New Gods as part of a massive two-man con with Wednesday/Odin.

**In the book, does Mr World represent/symbolise something specific among the New Gods?** The "fat kid" (called Technical Boy in the TV series) is clearly a god of [technical stuff like computers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/157118/31394), while Media ... well, the name says it all. Can Mr World as a god of globalisation be read from the novel? Or could he be a god of "everything", the whole world, enabling him to claim that role of leadership? Or something else?

Comment: There's more than one [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Gods)?

Comment: @Spencer No, that's just my habit leaking through, because most adaptations I've seen have been book *series* to film/TV series. Fixed.